# google interactive shell

Tags: google-app-engine, interactive-shell

I'm practically new to Google App Engine, but i have a homework to create some app with it.
I'm trying to debugging my app offline using google interactive shell. http://localhost:8080 looks fine, but when i tried to open http://localhost:8080/shell for debugging, it gave me broken URL. I have my directories checked, and they are fine for me.

I think my problem is in app.yaml file. Well, I know nothing about .yaml file, could anyone please tell me where I put something wrong in it?

Here's my app.yaml (I put all interactive shell properties in folder named 'shell')

```
application: myapp
version: 1

runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: shell/static
  expiration: 1d

- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py

- url: /shell.*
  script: shell/shell.py

- url: /
  script: myapp.py
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the error?

Comment: What is shell/shell.py? Where does it come from? And what is a "broken URL" precisely?

Comment: @NickJohnson I put shell.py and other properties such as static/* and templates/* folders in a folder named 'shell'

Comment: @DrewSears I get an error message like this _The webpage at http://localhost:8080/shell might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address._

Comment: @AlwinTyanto That's nice, but you haven't explained what shell.py is or where it comes from.

Comment: @NickJohnson well, shell.py is a file from Google Interactive Shell Code, I downloaded it from [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/downloads/detail?name=shell_20091112.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the shell.* be shell in yaml rule if you want to find it in http://localhost:8080/shell

```
- url: /shell
  script: shell/shell.py
```